# GAE: Prevent inadvertent overwriting of data

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Suppose I have an entity for a person with two properties:

```
class Person(ndb.Model)
    payments = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

I was thinking that I would update `payments` in a transaction but that I would not need transactions when updating `name`.

However, it seems that in the following scenario, that I could lose the value of `payments`:

```
TIME | INSTANCE1                 | INSTANCE2 (in transaction)
=====================================================
||   | person1 = key1.get()      |
||   | person1.name = "John"     | person1 = key1.get()
||   | [other stuff that]        | person1.payments = 100
||   | [takes some time]         | person1.put()
||   | person1.put()             |
||   |
\/
```

In this scenario, it seems that INSTANCE1 will overwrite the payment amount written in INSTANCE2 and that the payment amount will be lost.

Does this mean that I also need to use transactions when updating `name` to make sure that important data is never lost?

Or more generally, if I am using transactions to update any property of an entity, that I should use transactions for all updates to that entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will lose the new value of `payments` in this scenario. The datastore has no concept of updating a property value, an entity is always  fully overwritten.

> The Datastore API does not distinguish between creating a new entity and updating an existing one. If the object's key represents an entity that already exists, the put() method overwrites the existing entity.

When both are transactions, it works fine. This is how it plays out exactly.

> When a transaction starts, App Engine uses optimistic concurrency control by checking the last update time for the entity groups used in the transaction. Upon commiting a transaction for the entity groups, App Engine again checks the last update time for the entity groups used in the transaction. If it has changed since our initial check, an exception is thrown.

In this particular case, when the transaction in instance `A` is committed, App Engine notices that the entity has already been updated elsewhere since the transaction started. Transaction `A` is cancelled, and by default retried.

Answer (score 2):

The transaction is only in play during the .put() call... So your example will have the same effect in both instances regardless of whether you are using transactions or not. You will need to implement your own locking mechanism to identify whether an object has changed since it was loaded... Like checking a last_updated DateTimeProperty ... Then raising an exception (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control)

(Sorry for the bland formatting... I'm on a mobile browser)

Comment: oops... I misread this originally... for a single entities being saved outside of a transaction, then you would have to implement your own optimistic concurrency .... but if you are wrapping a bunch of work in a transaction, then what I said above is not really needed as the optimistic locking will be done for you by datastore and the entity-group

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it would probably be safest to use transactions for all updates to avoid the scenario you described.  Your only alternative (that I can think of) is to use a locking mechanism as suggested by @Nick Franceschina.